# A peculiar attraction

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme

> The lines you see below 
>   Mean one word each unique 
>   Which when put together 
>   Forms the answer you seek
>
> An exclusive group of people 
>   A city that’s eternal 
>   A book that’s periodical 
>   A trap to capture what’s feeble

What is the word?

Note: the words may overlap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are an:

> **ELECTROMAGNET**

*An exclusive group of people*

> The **ELECT** are a small group of people chosen by a much larger group as their representatives.

*A city that’s eternal*

> The 'Eternal City' is a nickname traditionally given to *Rome* in Italy. However, note that here we need its local name in Italian: **ROMA**.

*A book that’s periodical*

> A magazine is a periodical, and can be shortened to **MAG**.

*A trap to capture what’s feeble*

> A **NET** is a trap.

Put the letters together and you can make:

> **ELECTROMAGNET** - a peculiar *attraction* indeed (re the title)!

Comment: About the city. Maybe it supposed to be its native name instead of its english.
rot13(Ebzn vafgrnq bs ebzr)

Comment: Nice! @Bjorn is right. Please incorporate this into your answer so I can have it accepted.

Comment: @BjornEriksson Ah yes, as a Champions League follower I should have clicked with that earlier! Answer modified accordingly...